# How to control the playlist on yahoo webplayer?

Tags: yahoo-api

I have a self hosted wordpress site.  I have few posts with embedded mp3 files.  I am using yahoo web player currently.  It puts a little play icon in front of all the mp3 files.  Now, if the user clicks on one of the play icon, it loads the playlist with all the mp3 files in that page/post.

Is it possible to let the user pick the songs that they want to add to the playlist?

I am thinking of placing a little '+' icon for all the mp3 files and hoping that Yahoo has the necessary provision in the API.

Does anyone know a place where i can get the details on the API?  Google search was not of much help in this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some level of customization available, but might not be enough for the changes you're looking for.

Here is the official documentation: http://webplayer.yahoo.com/docs/